# One Product in cart at a time with multiple addons woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am creating a **subscription type of website** in which user will buy one plan suitable according to his needs and add one or two add-on product ( optional addons on checkout page or on pricing page)

User can only buy one plan at a time if he/she wants to buy another plan, first product from cart should get remove or ask user to remove existing product from cart.

After adding one product/plan in cart he/she can buy given optional addons

**Condition:

1. One product/plan at a time with optional addons
2. Addons are optional
3. Addons cannot purchased separately/individually**

Platform: woocomerce-wordpress

I tried to find any solution online but unable to find any like this in free or paid plugin but i need free one.

If anyone can recommend a free plugin or write some custom code for funtion.php file that would be very helpful